# Duplicate inserts to Database Table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

My code works perfectly. What it does is it scans a text file and retrieves user defined information and stores it into access. The only issue I'm having is that is when the code is ran again, it inserts data that has already been inserted.

Is there an easy way to fix this? One thing that the data all have in common is that they all have a timestamp. Is it possible to use this to prevent a duplicate?

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Main_Setup order by ID");
rows = cur.fetchall()
# outFileName = "out4.txt"

# The regex pattern that is used to extract timestamp from file
# it will search for timestamps like this 2017-06-13-22.31.30.978293
dateRegEx_1 = r"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]+"
dateRegEx_2 = r"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} \/ [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+"
# Compile the pattern
regdExPtrn_1 = re.compile(dateRegEx_1)
regdExPtrn_2 = re.compile(dateRegEx_2)
field_names = ''


# Call insertToAccess function to insert into access database

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM lastran order by ID')
tlran = cur.fetchall()

def insertLastran(JobName,timeStamp):
    print(JobName,timeStamp)

def insertToAccess(JobName, TableSeq, timeStamp, accessTableValues, field_names):


    # try:
    params = (JobName, timeStamp, TableSeq, accessTableValues[0], accessTableValues[1], accessTableValues[2],
              accessTableValues[3], accessTableValues[4], \
              accessTableValues[5], accessTableValues[6], accessTableValues[7], accessTableValues[8],
              accessTableValues[9], field_names)

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Report_Table (Job_Name,Run_TS,Seq_Num,Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5,Field6,Field7,Field8,Field9,Field10,Field11) VALUES \
                    (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", params);
    conn.commit()
    # except:
    #    conn.rollback()


# Extract the current job fields
def field_Extract(fileLines, fieldsArray, JobName, timeStamp, delimit):
    # Empty string in which we will append the
    # extracted fields
    matchStr = ""
    count = 0
    TableSeq = 0
    accessTableValues = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    field_names = ''
    for line in fileLines:
        for field in fieldsArray:
            if field in line:
                key, value = line.split(delimit)
                matchStr += key.strip() + "\t\t : " + value.strip() + "\n"
                accessTableValues[count] = value.strip()
                field_names += key.strip() + ';'
                count += 1
                if count == 10:
                    TableSeq += 1
                    insertToAccess(JobName, TableSeq, timeStamp, accessTableValues, field_names)
                    count = 0
                    accessTableValues = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                    field_names = ''
    if count > 0 and count < 10:
        TableSeq += 1
        insertToAccess(JobName, TableSeq, timeStamp, accessTableValues, field_names)

    # Return the string hold the extracted fields
    # Each field is onn a separate line
    return matchStr


# Open input and output files
test_file = open(r'C:\Users\cqt7wny\Desktop\new\SAVERS_REPT_DT0712.txt', 'r+')
# outFile = open(outFileName, 'w')

# Initialize used variables
currentJobData = []
startAppending = False
currentJobFound = False  # Gaurav note
fields_To_Extract = []
outFileStr = ""
for line in test_file:
    if startAppending == False:
        # for jobStart in job_start:
        if currentJobFound == False:
            # Find the job name for the current report and exit the loop    #====##########=====  Gaurav note
            for rowx in rows:
                if rowx[1] in line:
                    currentJobName = rowx[1]
                    search_Start_Point = rowx[2]
                    search_End_Point = rowx[3]
                    fields_To_Extract = rowx[4].split(';')
                    currentJobFound = True
                    break
            if currentJobName == 'xx':
                currentJobName = previousJobName
                search_Start_Point = previous_search_Start_Point
                search_End_Point = previous_search_End_Point
                fields_To_Extract = previous_fields_To_Extract

        if search_Start_Point in line:
            startAppending = True

    if startAppending == True:
        currentJobData.append(line)

    if len(search_End_Point) > 1 and (search_End_Point in line):
        # As a job end found, stop gathering lines
        startAppending = False
        # Get the time stamp
        # We search for it in the currnet line using the previously
        # compiled regex pattern
        txt = "".join(currentJobData)
        # Find all occurance of timestamps on the current job lines
        timeStamp = regdExPtrn_1.findall(txt)
        # Check that a timestamp found
        if len(timeStamp) >= 1:
            # If there is more than one timestamp in the current
            # job lines, get only the first one
            timeStamp = timeStamp[0]
        else:
            timeStamp = regdExPtrn_2.findall(txt)
            if len(timeStamp) >= 1:
                timeStamp = timeStamp[0]
                # Append the found output to the output string
        outFileStr += '########============ NEW JOB STARTS HERE ===========#########'
        outFileStr += "\n"
        outFileStr += "job# " + str(currentJobName)
        outFileStr += "\n"
        outFileStr += "Timestamp: " + timeStamp
        outFileStr += "\n"

        outFileStr = field_Extract(currentJobData, fields_To_Extract, currentJobName, timeStamp, ':')
        insertLastran(currentJobName,timeStamp)
        print('Current job Name :', currentJobName, ' : ', timeStamp)
        print(outFileStr)
        previousJobName = currentJobName
        previous_search_Start_Point = search_Start_Point
        previous_search_End_Point = search_End_Point
        previous_fields_To_Extract = fields_To_Extract

        currentJobName = 'xx'
        currentJobFound = False

        currentJobData = []
        fields_To_Extract = []
        search_Start_Point = ' '
        search_End_Point = ' '

test_file.close()
```

Comment: *My code works perfectly.* :-)

Comment: I have no idea how your db is set up but have you tried using `INSERT IGNORE` instead if your table has keys, or check for the rows existence before inserting?

Answer (score 0):

There can be different possible ways which can prevent duplicate inserts .

1.Check if already data is inserted/present in the Database/table.If it does not exists then Insert the data else ignore/do not insert the data .

2.You can Create a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on which you think the duplicacy exist .

like `ALTER TABLE MYTABLE ADD CONSTRAINT constraint1 UNIQUE(column1)`